# Form values convert into Form Class in Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel

Since I only know a simple select options on Laravel blade.

I need to convert a relationship value into Form:: class in Laravel blade .. please help me to convert this code into {{Form:: }}

```
<select name="department">
  @foreach($managers as $manager)
  <option value="{{$manager->user->id}}">{{$manager->user->name}}</option>
  @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Something like `Form::select('department', $managers, 'Pick one...');` I suppose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First Create an array like

```
$manageres = ['id' => 1,'name' => 'xyz'];
```

Pass array in blade file and use like below :

```
{!! Form::select('select_name', $managers, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
```

In the select() function :

- first argument is name of your select element
- second argument is your data array
- third argument is array of selected values
- fourth argument is class and all other properties array